# Kafka log retention worked abnormally, Why?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've set both of `log.roll.hours` and `log.retention.hours` in Kafka configs to 168 hours(7 days), and get `Configs:retention.ms=604800000` as output of `describe` command for one Topic.

But something weird happened for one Topic and Kafka deleted its log after rotation.

From kafka log

```
[2019-08-04 17:01:06,557] INFO  Found deletable segments with base offsets [546418] due to retention time 604800000ms breach (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-08-04 17:01:06,581] INFO  Writing producer snapshot at offset 715263 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2019-08-04 17:01:06,590] INFO  Rolled new log segment at offset 715263 in 32 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-08-04 17:01:06,590] INFO  Scheduling log segment [baseOffset 546418, size 28085295] for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-08-04 17:01:06,591] INFO  Incrementing log start offset to 715263 (kafka.log.Log)
```

And the output of `ll -h` command over the `kafka-log` directory is

```
ll -h
total 21M
drwxr-xr-x  2 kafka hadoop 4.0K Aug  5 13:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 59 kafka hadoop 4.0K Aug  5 15:24 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop  10M Aug  5 15:23 00000000000000715263.index
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 965K Aug  5 15:23 00000000000000715263.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop  10M Aug  5 15:23 00000000000000715263.timeindex
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop   10 Aug  5 13:39 00000000000000720418.snapshot
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop   37 Aug  5 13:41 leader-epoch-checkpoint
```

The problem is offset `715263` generated exactly at rotation time, Means I don't have an access to older data, But I expect to have an access to data of last 7 days.

Why Kafka behaves like that?

Comment: do you mean that the message with offset `715263` has been deleted?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous No, But it became the first available message in broker, But this message was generated exactly at log delete time and there should be more data before it.

Comment: Are you sure that the retention policy was not effective for the older messages as well?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Yes, because the retention file is accessible on replication machine and it was not deleted from it. Some how seems be a bug in Kafka log retention bug hard to reproduce.